# Using knit spin or stitch to interleave R into a template

Tags: r, knitr

This is probably documented somewhere, but I cannot find it ...

I have an .R file which can be used as a read_chunk() file and call from an .Rnw latex template or in a .Rmd file for primary review.

This design worked well for the first part of our project, but since the .R file will change, it's not 'reproducible research'.

Since I already have a 'template' with the named chunks referring to chunks in the read_chunk() file, is there any way to interleave the R into the .Rnw for posterity?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do, but look at the `stitch` function in `knitr` which is described as "Automatically create a report based on an R script and a template"

Comment: I don't think this functionality currently exists; I have an Rnw "template" that I use with read_chunk of an R file, but I'd like to actually interleave the R chunks into the document when I am ready to send the report. The general format of the report is the same, but produced periodically for different clients, so the data changes  and we add text.

Comment: Let me see if I can paraphrase: you have an `.Rnw` file which includes chunks that use the `read_chunk()` function to specify the `R` code to run. You want something that will take these two files and produce a new `.Rnw` file where the appropriate `R` code is now explicitly listed in the file (the calls to `read_chunk` are replaced with the code returned by that function). (Or replace `.Rmd` for `.Rnw` in that description.) Have I got it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the reverse operation of `purl()`, I believe. I don't know any such function, but technically it doesn't seem too hard; all the pieces are there:

```
chunks <- knitr:::knit_code$get()
for(k in names(chunks))
  cat(c(sprintf("<<%s>>=", k), chunks[[k]], "@\n"), sep = "\n")
```

would return all the chunks in a format suitable for inclusion in the Rnw file.

Comment: I need a bit more than the opposite of `purl()`  ... essentially I'd like a chunk library where I can choose which chunks are included in a given document and be able to use Rnw or Rmd. My draft version is called `weft()`